# Creating a sha256 signature using openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa, sha1, signing, sha256

I need to create a **SHA256** signature using **OpenSSL** ?

I tried:

```
  openssl sha256 -sha256 -binary -sign (providing my priv key & contents)
```

But, I get the following error : `openssl:Error: 'sha256' is an invalid command.`

sha1 works fine, but I thought sha256 was supported as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSL uses the command '[dgst](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dgst.html)' to calculate various digests (including SHA-256). The command also allows you to sign a digest (using a private key) and verify a signature (using a public key).